# XML file flat to tree structure grouping fields

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, xslt-2.0

I am new to XSL transformations and I want to transform the XML A into XML B .Any suggestions to achieve this in XSLT or xquery. I tried using for-each-group on msisdn
but still unable to achieve it.Any sample code to start with

XML A:

```
<Output>
<response>
    <msisdn>27832007509</msisdn>
    <bearer>DATA</bearer>
    <comb_charged_units>4223777792</comb_charged_units>
    <comb_cnt>288</comb_cnt>
    <shared_voice_duration>0</shared_voice_duration>
    <shared_data_volume>8728127</shared_data_volume>
    <shared_voice_cnt>0</shared_voice_cnt>
    <shared_data_cnt>89</shared_data_cnt>
</response>
<response>
    <msisdn>27832007509</msisdn>
    <bearer>VOICE</bearer> 
    <comb_charged_units>477792</comb_charged_units>
    <comb_cnt>281</comb_cnt>
    <shared_voice_duration>17268127877</shared_voice_duration>
    <shared_data_volume>0</shared_data_volume>
    <shared_voice_cnt>87887</shared_voice_cnt>
    <shared_data_cnt>0</shared_data_cnt>
</response>
<response>
    <msisdn>27832229588</msisdn>
    <bearer>DATA</bearer>
    <comb_charged_units>11898</comb_charged_units>
    <comb_cnt>33</comb_cnt>
    <shared_voice_duration>0</shared_voice_duration>
    <shared_data_volume>3445</shared_data_volume>
    <shared_voice_cnt>0</shared_voice_cnt>
    <shared_data_cnt>78</shared_data_cnt>
</response>
<response>
    <msisdn>27832229588</msisdn>
    <bearer>VOICE</bearer>
    <comb_charged_units>45</comb_charged_units>
    <comb_cnt>12</comb_cnt>
    <shared_voice_duration>789</shared_voice_duration>
    <shared_data_volume>0</shared_data_volume>
    <shared_voice_cnt>23</shared_voice_cnt>
    <shared_data_cnt>0</shared_data_cnt>
</response>
```

XML B:

```
<UsageHistoryResponse>
<usage>
    <MSISDN>27832007509</MSISDN>
    <CombinedUsage>
        <usage_info>
            <bearer>DATA</bearer>
            <bearer_units>288</bearer_units>
            <bearer_units_uom>Sessions</bearer_units_uom>
            <bearer_usage>4223777792</bearer_usage>
            <bearer_usage_uom>bytes</bearer_usage_uom>
        </usage_info>
        <usage_info>
            <bearer>VOICE</bearer>
            <bearer_units>281</bearer_units>
            <bearer_units_uom>Calls</bearer_units_uom>
            <bearer_usage>477792</bearer_usage>
            <bearer_usage_uom>Seconds</bearer_usage_uom>
        </usage_info>
    </CombinedUsage>
    <SharedUsage>
        <usage_info>
            <bearer>DATA</bearer>
            <bearer_units>89</bearer_units>
            <bearer_units_uom>Sessions</bearer_units_uom>
            <bearer_usage>8728127</bearer_usage>
            <bearer_usage_uom>bytes</bearer_usage_uom>
        </usage_info>
        <usage_info>
            <bearer>VOICE</bearer>
            <bearer_units>87887</bearer_units>
            <bearer_units_uom>Calls</bearer_units_uom>
            <bearer_usage>17268127877</bearer_usage>
            <bearer_usage_uom>Seconds</bearer_usage_uom>
        </usage_info>
    </SharedUsage>
</usage>
<usage>
    <MSISDN>27832229588</MSISDN>
    <CombinedUsage>
        <usage_info>
            <bearer>DATA</bearer>
            <bearer_units>33</bearer_units>
            <bearer_units_uom>Sessions</bearer_units_uom>
            <bearer_usage>11898</bearer_usage>
            <bearer_usage_uom>bytes</bearer_usage_uom>
        </usage_info>
        <usage_info>
            <bearer>VOICE</bearer>
            <bearer_units>12</bearer_units>
            <bearer_units_uom>Calls</bearer_units_uom>
            <bearer_usage>45</bearer_usage>
            <bearer_usage_uom>Seconds</bearer_usage_uom>
        </usage_info>
    </CombinedUsage>
    <SharedUsage>
        <usage_info>
            <bearer>DATA</bearer>
            <bearer_units>78</bearer_units>
            <bearer_units_uom>Sessions</bearer_units_uom>
            <bearer_usage>3445</bearer_usage>
            <bearer_usage_uom>bytes</bearer_usage_uom>
        </usage_info>
        <usage_info>
            <bearer>VOICE</bearer>
            <bearer_units>23</bearer_units>
            <bearer_units_uom>Calls</bearer_units_uom>
            <bearer_usage>789</bearer_usage>
            <bearer_usage_uom>Seconds</bearer_usage_uom>
        </usage_info>
    </SharedUsage>
</usage>
```

My idea is to group msisdn first and then traverse into fields of it. Below is my attempt

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <tns:UsageHistoryResponse>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Output/response">
            <tns:usage>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="." group-by="ns0:msisdn">
                    <tns:MSISDN>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></tns:MSISDN>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </tns:usage>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tns:UsageHistoryResponse>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: "*I tried using for-each-group on msisdn*" Post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that shows how to achieve the grouping and addition of two wrapper elements:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Output">
        <UsageHistoryResponse>         
            <xsl:for-each-group select="response" group-by="msisdn">
              <usage>
                <MSISDN>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                </MSISDN>  
                <CombinedUsage>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </CombinedUsage>
                <SharedUsage>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="shared"/>
                </SharedUsage>
              </usage>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </UsageHistoryResponse> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="response" mode="#default shared">
        <usage_info>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
        </usage_info>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="msisdn" mode="#all"/>

    <xsl:template match="response/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'shared')]"/>

    <xsl:template match="response/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'comb')]" mode="shared"/>

    <xsl:template match="comb_cnt">
        <bearer_units>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </bearer_units>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKb/1 shows it gives

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UsageHistoryResponse>
   <usage>
      <MSISDN>27832007509</MSISDN>
      <CombinedUsage>
         <usage_info>
            <bearer>DATA</bearer>
            <comb_charged_units>4223777792</comb_charged_units>
            <bearer_units>288</bearer_units>
         </usage_info>
         <usage_info>
            <bearer>VOICE</bearer>
            <comb_charged_units>477792</comb_charged_units>
            <bearer_units>281</bearer_units>
         </usage_info>
      </CombinedUsage>
      <SharedUsage>
         <usage_info>
            <bearer>DATA</bearer>
            <shared_voice_duration>0</shared_voice_duration>
            <shared_data_volume>8728127</shared_data_volume>
            <shared_voice_cnt>0</shared_voice_cnt>
            <shared_data_cnt>89</shared_data_cnt>
         </usage_info>
         <usage_info>
            <bearer>VOICE</bearer>
            <shared_voice_duration>17268127877</shared_voice_duration>
            <shared_data_volume>0</shared_data_volume>
            <shared_voice_cnt>87887</shared_voice_cnt>
            <shared_data_cnt>0</shared_data_cnt>
         </usage_info>
      </SharedUsage>
   </usage>
   <usage>
      <MSISDN>27832229588</MSISDN>
      <CombinedUsage>
         <usage_info>
            <bearer>DATA</bearer>
            <comb_charged_units>11898</comb_charged_units>
            <bearer_units>33</bearer_units>
         </usage_info>
         <usage_info>
            <bearer>VOICE</bearer>
            <comb_charged_units>45</comb_charged_units>
            <bearer_units>12</bearer_units>
         </usage_info>
      </CombinedUsage>
      <SharedUsage>
         <usage_info>
            <bearer>DATA</bearer>
            <shared_voice_duration>0</shared_voice_duration>
            <shared_data_volume>3445</shared_data_volume>
            <shared_voice_cnt>0</shared_voice_cnt>
            <shared_data_cnt>78</shared_data_cnt>
         </usage_info>
         <usage_info>
            <bearer>VOICE</bearer>
            <shared_voice_duration>789</shared_voice_duration>
            <shared_data_volume>0</shared_data_volume>
            <shared_voice_cnt>23</shared_voice_cnt>
            <shared_data_cnt>0</shared_data_cnt>
         </usage_info>
      </SharedUsage>
   </usage>
</UsageHistoryResponse>
```

so some work is left to rename elements which can be simply achieve by adding templates doing that and then you also seem to want to add some data, I am not sure where that data like

```
<bearer_usage_uom>Seconds</bearer_usage_uom>
```

is supposed to be taken from.

As for an explanation: I have used `for-each-group` as you wanted to and as the tool that XSLT 2.0 offers for grouping, only I have used the right population (`select="response"`) in the right context (`match="Output"`). If you struggle to understand that then try a tutorial on XSLT 2.0 grouping. As you seem to want to process each item in a group twice, I have then used modes to do that, so to build the `CombinedUsage` I have used the default mode, to build the `SharedUsaged`  I have used a different mode. The rest is then writing templates for the elements in the input to be mapped to the elements in the output and making sure the elements you don't want in the result for a certain mode are not copied by using empty templates for them.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Martin .I need two usage tags  in XML B since there are two different msisdn in XML A.

Comment: @NaveenzRock, I have corrected the `usage` element position, somehow im my first attempt I had put it outside of the `for-each-group` while you need it inside.

Comment: Can u give explanation.My logic is goin to little be more complex(for me at least).I want to understand this logic and build the final xsl. the website u shared is good.directly we can edit things

Comment: @NaveenzRock, I have added some explanation, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-2.0/info for courses/tutorials if you need a deeper and broader introduction to XSLT and XPath 2.0.

Comment: ,The output given by you is not the desired one.because if you observe in your output, tags inside <SharedUsage> hold same values as that of <CombinedUsage> ,which is not as per XML B.Can u please make this correction and update your answer

Comment: @NaveenzRock, I have corrected one issue so that I think now for `SharedUsage` the right elements are processed, but as I said, the answer is an attempt to show you how to use `for-each-group` to get the main structure of your desired output,  it is not a spelled-out stylesheet to implement all details of your transformation.

Comment: Okay.I can edit fine in the website u shared but my ide (Jdev12c ,using oracle xslt processor) gives me error at the value of mode attribute in template.The Error is... Value of attribute mode not of QName type :Th value must be one of the following types 1)NCName With the following constraints matching the pattern :[\i[:]][\c-[:]]* 2)Qname .Any fix for this ?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know anything about that XSLT processor and how far it implements the XSLT 2.0 specification as published ten years ago. In the Java world I would suggest to move to Saxon 9 if you want to use XSLT 2.0 or 3.0, it's open-source Home Edition HE is available on Maven and Sourceforge.